# What is more efficient to copy a folder with a lot of files in Amazon S3 using Hadoop API in java, FileUtil.copy() or DistCp.run()

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-s3, distcp

I'm trying to create a copy of a folder with a lot of files in Amazon S3.Both the source path and the target path are in a s3 bucket.But i don't really know what option is more efficient, the FileUtil.copy()  option or the Distcp.run() option. Both options are easy to implement, i'm just worried about efficiency since i heard that distcp will create a copy in the hadoop filesystem then transfer it to the s3 bucket.

Comment: Where have you heard distcp makes a copy? Could you run it on a few files and prove that?

Comment: I have tested, both distcp and fileutil make a copy, but i want to know which one would be more efficient in a cluster with a lot of files

Comment: Distcp is, and it should run faster for a large volume of files, but I cannot prove that